# Can you help clarify my server's NUMA configuration?

Tags: sql-server, numa, sql-server-2022

I have a SQL Server 2022 Enterprise instance in a VMWare VM.  We upgraded this instance last week from Standard to Enterprise and I want to now make sure we use the appropriate instance level setting for MAXDOP.  The VM has a single NUMA node (NUMA Nodes is grayed out in Task Manager|CPU).

The SQL Server log shows this:
[image]

Soft NUMA is enabled, and the way I understand the output is there are 3 soft NUMA nodes.

However, when I query `sys.dm_os_memory_nodes` I read the output as having 2 NUMA nodes, plus the one dedicated for admin connection (memory_node_id 64).

[image]

Something further that is throwing me off is the results of this query of `sys.dm_os_memory_clerks`:

[image]

Can someone help me to confirm how many nodes I actually have?  Are the log output and the results of `sys.dm_os_memory_nodes` giving me what I want, and I have 2 nodes plus the dedicated admin connection?  If that's the case, what is the query from `sys.dm_os_memory_clerks` telling me?

**EDIT:**
Here is the output of `sys.dm_os_nodes` as requested.
[image]

Comment: What does sys.dm_os_nodes show? Soft-NUMA mapping should be exposed through this view. As an aside: if you have 10 sockets with 2 cores each, I'm concerned that the underlying hardware NUMA nodes may not be correctly exposed to the VM

Comment: @rois I added a screenshot.  It shows 3, which aligns with the log output.  And I also had the same concern about underlying hardware NUMA.  I'm not sure if I'll be able to do anything about it as the VM automatically managed and hosted in a huge VMWare cluster...